# Multiple oracle queries problem

Tags: .net, sql, oracle, multiple-tables

I'm trying to run a query from a .NET page but I seem to having some problems with having multiple queries.

My query is similar to this

`SELECT * FROM table1; SELECT * from table2`

But i seem to get an invalid character error when executing this from a .Net page. It runs fine in SQL developer but only fails when i put it in my .NET page.

I've added the `BEGIN` and `END` to the query as some websites suggest you need this to run multiple queries but then I get the following error

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>   PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

Can anyone shed any light on this one?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Here's some code

```
        query = conn.CreateCommand()

        query.CommandText = "SELECT * from table1; SELECT * FROM table2;"

        DataSet = New DataSet()
        DataAdapter = New DataAdapter(query)
        DataAdapter.Fill(DataSet)

        datagrid1.DataSource = DataSet.Tables(0)
        datagrid1.DataBind()

        lbl1.Text = DataSet.Tables(1).Rows(0).Item("column1").ToString()
```

Comment: What do you expect to receive? PL-SQL explicitly denies to `SELECT` without using the result.

Comment: @grep: Basically I want to databind a datagrid with the results of one table and populate a label with the results of the other table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to pull from 2 tables and get a DataSet that you can fill into a DataAdapter, then you need to use one of the following approaches:

1. join the 2 tables together (may or may not be possible depending on your tables)
2. union the 2 tables (this may or may not be applicable to your scenario)
3. write a stored procedure which creates whatever result you need and returns it in a ref cursor. You can read about how to do that [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

You're not going to be able to just run 2 SQL statements like that and get any meaningful result into a DataSet.

Comment: Thanks - i'll try one of those appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for stating the obvious but:

1.. Make 2 calls

or

2.. Put the selects in a stored procedure and return 2 refcursors

here's a good link on Working with Multiple Result Sets:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971506.aspx#msdnorsps_topic13

Answer (score 0):

If you only need fields that are present in both table1 and table2 you can do

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM table1
UNION
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM table2
```

If the fields have different names but the same type of content you can do

```
SELECT tab1_id AS primary_key, tab1_name AS name, tab1_amount AS amount FROM table1
UNION
SELECT tab2_id AS primary_key, tab2_name AS name, tab2_amount AS amount FROM table2
```

This will give you a result with the columns primary_key, name, amount (this is just a random example)

If the two tables contain completely different content, you should really use two separate queries.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be

```
query.CommandText = "BEGIN OPEN :1 FOR SELECT * FROM table1; OPEN :2 FOR SELECT * FROM table2; END;";
```

... as found in [DataSet.Load: Loading multiple tables with System.Data.OracleClient.OracleDataReader](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/4f977ccc-5122-4d83-ac7c-c7fd3c6cdb54) ... but not tested myself.

Also check out http://forums.asp.net/t/629511.aspx/1. It shows how, sort of. I added a reference to Oracle.DataAccess.Types;, but still had a problem. It's close though.